# Is it possible to check the "long double" type being used?

Tags: floating-point, double, long-double

I'd like that an application would be able to know if it's running on a system whose "long double" type is a synonym for "double", or a true 128bit IEEE quad precision, or an 80bit Intel extended format, or a "double-double".

Is it possible to check this at runtime? How?

Comment: does `sizeof` meet your requirements?

Comment: I don't think so: sizeof(long double) will return 16 for true 128bit IEEE, for "double double", and for 80bit Intel on some systems. However, it would allow to check if "long double" is a synonym for double on the system.

Comment: I don't have a way to test all formats mentioned, so won't write an answer. You should be able to distinguish these formats by computing `1 + eps - 1`, for appropriate values of `eps`. Chose `eps` such that the result is zero for the narrower format, but `eps` for the next wider format. E.g. with `eps = 0x1.0p-120`, `1 + eps` is representable as a double-double, but rounds to 1 for a 128-bit IEEE-754 `binary128` quadruple precision format.

Comment: Do you have a language in mind? e.g., [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) in `<limits>` for C++11, makes this relatively easy.

Comment: @BrettHale: Language can be either C or C++, but I prefer to avoid a version requirement, such as C++11. Anyway, the definitions in <float.h> available for almost every C compiler can provide the same aid.

Comment: @njuffa: Thanks a lot, the epsilon trick, combined with sizeof() and perhaps some binary magic, can be everything I need.